# PackageNotFound error when installing bioconductor-deseq2 in miniconda3

Tags: conda, channel, bioconductor, miniconda, installation-package

I'm new to conda and trying to install featureCounts contained in DESeq2 package. I've added four channels: r, conda-forge, defaults, and bioconda. But when I type in the command 
        `conda install bioconductor-deseq2`
I always get the following error message:

```
(base) C:\Users\huand>conda install bioconductor-deseq2
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - bioconductor-deseq2

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/r/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

does anyone know where the problem is? Or which channel should I add in order to install deseq2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the search feature on [anaconda.org](https://anaconda.org/search?q=bioconductor-deseq2) to get information on how to install a package. For your package it looks like this:

[image]

Meaning that, in principle, the package is available from the channels

```
bioconda
iuc
bgruening
guillaumecharbonnier
```

Note however, that under `Platforms`, only `linux-64` and `osx-64` are listed, no `win64`, which is the platform you are using. The package you are looking for can therefore not be installed on windows using `conda`. you will need to install it another way, maybe by downloading from [their website directly](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/DESeq2.html)